# Do the words "take advice" / "taken advice" imply the advisor is a lawyer?

Tags: legal-terms

As per the title, I am (as a non-lawyer) helping someone in a dispute where fraud has occurred.

If I'm helping the person write a letter to one of the involved parties based on my advice, if I help her produce a letter which says she has "taken advice" (and I am the one advising her), would this be construed as a claim she has received advice specifically from a lawyer?

Put another way, if someone claims to have "taken advice", and the advice they received was from a non-lawyer, is the claim misleading?

Comment: Could someone answer whether this makes any difference legally? "I have taken advice, and I believe you should pay me £100 for my damages within 14 days". Does it make a difference legally whether a lawyer told me this, or some bloke in the pub, or I made it up?

Comment: @gnasher729 - it might. If falsely advised them "this comes from a lawyer", they might be justified in thinking that this is a legal opinion [from a lawyer with obligations to the crown] and will behave based on that opinion.   I agree in practice its not likely to make much difference unless a relevant duty can be proved between the sender of the letter and the recipient , but I also don't want to give the person I'm helping the wrong idea.

Comment: Is it actually legal advice and are you concerned about UPL separate from the wording you are asking about?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Im not sure if, were I to say the exact thing as a lawyer, it would be legal advice.   Im not worried about practicing law unlawfully.  Words have meanings though, and Im unsure if I understand the meaning of these adequately.

Comment: @davidgo Why use the phrase at all? Does it add any value to the intended message?

Comment: @rockape I wanted to send a secondary message to the adversary that they are no longer just dealing with a naive sucker - without offending the naive sucker who I am trying to assist.

Comment: @davidgo "*they might be justified in thinking that this is a legal opinion [from a lawyer with obligations to the crown] and will behave based on that opinion*". That is not actionable. The adversary is not supposed to place greater reliance merely on grounds that the defrauded person alleges his position or claim is endorsed by some lawyer.

Comment: @gnasher729: The problem with that statement is that the professional may be someone who professionally assessed the damage at £100. That professional could still be a car mechanic, who in fact may be more qualified to make that assessment than a lawyer would be,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive that in British English, and other versions of English derived from BrE, "to have taken advice" usually means to have obtained a formal professional opinion, often from a lawyer, but it could be from an accountant, an architect, or any other sort of professional.

To use such a phrase in a business letter might well imply having obtained a professional opinion of some sort, and be misleading if the advice was casual or personal instead of professional.  Even if the phrase was misleading, that might not be a legal issue, depending on the circumstances of the letter.

If the issue is a specifically legal one, any professional advice would most likely be legal advice, and **in that case** that would be the implication of the phrase, I would think.

Comment: Also, if the OP is not a lawyer and the advice is legal advice they are breaking the law

Comment: @DaleM That is not at all clear. In many jurisdictions "practice of law" in this sense  is limited to representing a person in court or at a hearing, or preparing documents or giving advice for a fee or as on';re primary duty as an employee.This is true of Alabama and Colorado, for example. Unpaid occasional giving of advice by a non-lawyer who does not claim to be a lawyer is not UPL in many places. In the US there might be a First Amendment issue in such a charge.

Answer (score 3):

> if someone claims to have "taken advice", and the advice they received was from a non-lawyer, is the claim misleading?

No. The language "*taken advice*" does not imply "*taken legal advice*", let alone one arising from an attorney-client relation or taken from someone purporting to be a lawyer.

The language "*taken advice*" in and of itself leaves the advisor's capacity unspecified. For instance, the non-lawyer might be an accountant whose advice goes beyond a lawyer's scope or expertise.

That being said, it is unclear whether adding that expression is useful at all.